# unable to pass dict into tpl function (actually anything but <dot>')

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm new to helm/go templating, and it seems that I still don't understand how context work. Can someone explain, where is problem and why dict cannot be used like this?

I have this template in file `stubs/.test.yaml` (which I'd like to use with tpl function):

```
test: abc
test2: {{.Values.key}}
```

in values.yaml there is just:

```
key: value
```

and I include this template like this:

```
{{ tpl (.Files.Get "stubs/.test.yaml" ) (.) }}
```

produces:

```
test: abc
test2: value
```

So I loaded file from stubs/.test.yaml, and passed it current (root) context, and `.Values.key` was found and substituted. As expected.

Now lets redefine `stubs/.test.yaml` as:

```
test: abc
test2: {{.key}}
```

and pass a dict as a context when substituting template, as:

```
{{ tpl (.Files.Get "stubs/.test.yaml" ) (dict "key" .Values.key) }}
```

so I'd expect the same result, since I passed dict in place of root context, dict has single value named `key`, with value taken from `.Values.key`, which is correctly referenced in that template. But I got:

```
error calling tpl: cannot retrieve Template.Basepath from values inside tpl function: test: abc
test2: {{.key}}: "BasePath" is not a value
```

instead. What is happening here?

EDIT: I was testing it more, and it's not about dict. I have to pass `.` as second parameter into tpl function, otherwise it fails.

Version 3.10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found answer in this [issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5979)

IIUC: before `tpl` starts, it creates object `.Template` (see [builtin_objects](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/)) in root context, where there are data about currently processed template. So if you are using `tpl` you must not change context and pass `.`, or you must pass *something* as context, from what is valid $.Template accessible.

So if we're passing dict as in example in my question:

```
{{ tpl (.Files.Get "stubs/.test.yaml" ) (dict "key" .Values.key) }}
```

it will not work. But if you extend dict definition like this:

```
{{ tpl (.Files.Get "stubs/.test.yaml" ) (dict "key" .Values.key "Template" $.Template) }}
```

it will work now.